# Get all children and its grand children - hibernate

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, hql

I have the table structure as follows

```
req_id parent_req_id
1        null
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        2
6        2
7        3
```

I need to write a HQL query where if i input as 1, i need to retrieve 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. Since 2,3,4 are the immediate children of 1 and 5,6,7 being its grandchildren. Please find the bean structure for hiberate below

```
            @Entity
            @Table(name = "requirements")
            public class RequirementsDTO implements Serializable {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Id
                @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
                @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
                @Basic(optional = false)
                @Column(name = "req_id")
                private Integer reqId;
                @Column(name = "req_name")
                private String reqName;
                @Column(name = "req_desc")
                private String reqDesc;
                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "reqId")
                private List<RequirementActorsDTO> requirementActorsDTOList;
                @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentReqId")
                private List<RequirementsDTO> requirementsDTOList;
                @JoinColumn(name = "parent_req_id", referencedColumnName = "req_id")
                @ManyToOne
                private RequirementsDTO parentReqId;
                //getters and setters
            }
```

Comment: I have derived a HQL query to get the immediate children. I do not have any idea to go beyond that.

Comment: Which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) are you using? This can easily be solved with a recursive query.

Comment: I am using MySQL as my DBMS. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Well, MySQL is the only (major) DBMS to not support recursive queries. You will need to write a stored procedure or do it in your Java code.

Comment: Still unclear as to what you want, but my answer is definitely not it.

Comment: I have edited the column names in the question. What i want is if the user gives input as 1, i need to match all the children and grand children of the node which has a requirement id 1